How to select data-cy locator if it contains a changeable attribute?
Lets assume I have a document storage and every document has a menu. Menu button has data-cy locator with the name of the document. How do I make it right in the code?
data-cy="PDF file # 1939-dropdown"

where '-dropdown' part is permanent and 'PDF file # 1939' is changing depends on file.
i am expecting something like
dropDownLocator = '{fileName}-dropdown'
But I dont know how to make it right.

If you have an attribute data-cy="PDF file # 1939-dropdown" on an element, you can find it in several ways.
Exact match
cy.get(`[data-cy="PDF file # ${fileName}-dropdown"]`)

Starts-with match ^=
cy.get(`[data-cy^="PDF file # ${fileName}"]`)

Contains match *=
cy.get(`[data-cy*="${fileName}"]`)

Contains word match ~=
cy.get(`[data-cy~="${fileName}-dropdown"]`)

A complete list is here jQuery attribute selectors
All the above inject the fileName using a template literal, which assumes you have the document number in a variable.
An example with regex is shown here How can I use regex on an attribute value in cy.get()?. It explains the pitfalls and recommends jQuery attribute selectors instead.
It also shows use of combined attribute selectors if you want to exclude part of the attribute value from the match (e.g you want all documents regardless of the document number).

You can use Template literals to inject the PDF number.
The syntax is very similar to the pattern you asked for above, except using back-ticks for the delimiters and injecting the filename using ${}.
const dropDownLocator = `[data-cy="PDF file # ${fileName}-dropdown"]`

cy.get(dropDownLocator)


thanks. this is exactly what i used : cy.get([data-cy="${fileName}-dropdown"])

It's not "exactly" the same - you missed out the PDF file #  part. Without it the query will fail.

'PDF file # ' is also a part of variable in my case.... it can be JPG file # etc.

You can use a regex-type matcher within a CSS selector. In this case, you could match on data-cy attributes that end in -dropdown.
cy.get('[data-cy$="-dropdown"]');

